# I've been facing a persistent issue with the Facebook API regarding the pages_read_user_content permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I've been facing a persistent issue with the Facebook API regarding the **`pages_read_user_content`** permission. My application requires this permission to access and retrieve content from users' pages. However, I've noticed that Facebook keeps denying this permission request, even after multiple attempts.

I have followed the official documentation thoroughly and made sure to implement the necessary steps for requesting permissions. Here's what I've done:

1. Registered my app on the Facebook Developer Portal.
2. Configured the required OAuth login flow for users.
3. Requested the **`pages_read_user_content`** permission explicitly in my login dialog.
4. Handled the permissions callback properly to retrieve access tokens.

Despite adhering to these guidelines, the permission request for **`pages_read_user_content`** is repeatedly denied. I've checked for potential reasons, such as incorrect app configuration or misinterpreting the documentation, but everything seems to be in order.

Has anyone else encountered this issue recently? Is there a common mistake or something that I might be overlooking? Are there any changes in the Facebook API or permissions system that I should be aware of?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this problem. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Try the `pages_read_engagement` permission. This allows you to access the `/<page>/posts` endpoint (but not `/<page>/feed`). This permission seems easier to get than `pages_read_user_content`.

Comment: I want the post comment API as well, and it's not in pages_read_engagement.